# How do I execute a hook on devise's login to provide extra rules for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to do a 'basecamp-style' subdomain arrangement. I've got the subdomains working just fine. I'm just trying to restrict login based upon the subdomain, so users are only authorised on subdomains to which they have access.

Where can I add a hook that is executed when devise is performing authorisation to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to redefine the class method `find_for_authentication` in your user model. You can find the devise default implementation in `lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb`